# Fetching via wget to memory & bypassing disk writes

Tags: pipe, wget, io-redirection, ramdisk

Is it possible to download contents of a website—a set of HTML pages—straight to memory without writing out to disk?

I have a cluster of machines with 24G of installed each, but I’m limited by a disk quota to several hundreds MB. I was thinking of redirecting the output `wget` to some kind of in-memory structure without storing the contents on a disk. The other option is to create my own version of `wget` but may be there is a simple way to do it with pipes

Also what would be the best way to run this download in parallel (the cluster has >20 nodes). Can’t use the file system in this case.

Comment: Are you fetching that *set of pages* using `wget --recursive` ?

Comment: Well, it sounds like the solution is getting a higher quota. When faced with a similar problem, I purchased really big disks for the machine and had the sysadmins set them up for me. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See [wget download options](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options):

> > ‘-O file’
> >
> > ‘--output-document=file’
> >
> > The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated together and written to file. If ‘-’ is used as file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link conversion. (Use ‘./-’ to print to a file literally named ‘-’.)

If you want to read the files into a Perl program, you can invoke `wget` using backticks.

Depending on what you *really* need to do, you might be able to get by just using [LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/LWP::Simple)'s `get`.

```
use LWP::Simple;
my $content = get("http://www.example.com/");
die "Couldn't get it!" unless defined $content;
```

**Update:** I had *no idea* you could implement your own file system in Perl using [Fuse](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) and [Fuse.pm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Fuse). See also [Fuse::InMemory](http://notabilis.org/code/?ramfuse).

Answer (score 5):

Are you root? You could just use a `tmpfs`.

Re your edit: you're not CPU bound, you don't need to use every machine. You can use `xargs -n SOME_NUMBER` to split your list of root urls, assuming there are several.

But if you are keen on sharing memory, you can set up a cluster memcache and mount it on every machine with [memcachefs](http://memcachefs.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: It so happens that Linux has a `tmpfs` mounted at `/dev/shm`, accessible for everyone (not just root).  Not that you *should* abuse it for this purpose, but... ;-)

Comment: Depends on your setup and your distro, you may or may not have tmpfs already mounted at /dev/shm.

Comment: @ephemient You are a bad person. (incidentally, /var/lock also works)

Comment: @davr: Any Linux distribution using Glibc≥2.2 and that wishes to be POSIX.1-compliant has `/dev/shm` mounted; Glibc implements POSIX shared memory (`shm_open`) via files in that directory.

Answer (score 5):

If you a) are already using Perl, b) want to download HTML, and c) parse it, I always recommend [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP) and [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Tree).

Answer (score 2):

```
wget <url> -O -
```

Will write the contents of a URL to standard output, which can then be captured in memory.